# How can I get Kupfer to respond to keystrokes?

Tags: shortcut-keys, kupfer

[Kupfer](http://engla.github.io/kupfer/) is a keyboard-oriented program, so it's strange that it suddenly **won't respond to any key commands**. Once I summon it, the window pops up, but nothing I type has any effect.

Comment: Does the kupfer window have focus? Can you type something in **after** you clicked inside the kupfer window?

Comment: Nope. I click in the window and try to type stuff, and it doesn't respond.

Comment: Could never solve this problem, by the way. I ended up having to delete my kupfer config files and start over. Maybe it was a bug with a plugin.

Comment: @Jon Did the keystrokes **work normally** after you deleted the config files of Kupfer? Can you confirm whether you deleted `~/.config/kupfer/` or state other paths, please? Which **Ubuntu version** did you use at that time (please edit your post)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start kupfer using the `kupfer --debug` command and try again: that won't make it work but will at least give you a hint on why it doesn't work.

It is likely that some plugin causes an error preventing kupfer from working.

I had this issue with the Empathy plugin and it has bothered me for hours.

Comment: Here is [output](http://pastebin.com/EKEJpSxy) when I start Kupfer in debug mode. Any ideas?

Comment: @JJD: Seems the firefox3 plugin fails for some reason. It's lookup up a key named `children` that doesn't exist in the `next` dictionary. I never used that plugin (nor Firefox for that matter) so I have no idea what could be wrong. You should contact the plugin author, perhaps he has a clue.

Comment: I disabled almost all plugins and enabled firefox3 again. Now it works. Must be one of the others. I leave it like that for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Does your window manager have "auto-raise" (automatic focusing of windows as the cursor moves over them) enabled? If so, then unless your mouse is already in the area on the screen where Kupfer shows itself, then focus will immediately revert to any window that the mouse is currently over.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I deleted a folder that was in the catalog of folders for Kupfer to monitor.  I had to do a complete uninstall and reinstall via synaptic to resume normal function.