# How to autostart Kupfer in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, autostart, kupfer

I built [Kupfer](http://engla.github.io/kupfer/) from source on Ubuntu 13.10 and installed it into `./local`. In the preferences I checked `Start automatically on login`.

[image: Kupfer Preferences]

However, Kupfer does not automatically start.

The desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications/kupfer.desktop` looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Kupfer
Name[cs]=Kupfer
Name[da]=Kupfer
Name[de]=Kupfer
Name[el]=Kupfer
Name[es]=Kupfer
Name[eu]=Kupfer
Name[fr]=Kupfer
Name[gl]=Kupfer
Name[hu]=Kupfer
Name[it]=Kupfer
Name[ko]=쿠퍼
Name[nb]=Kupfer
Name[nl]=Kupfer
Name[pl]=Kupfer
Name[pt]=Kupfer
Name[pt_BR]=Kupfer
Name[ru]=Kupfer
Name[sl]=Kupfer
Name[sv]=Kupfer
Name[tr]=Kupfer
Name[zh_CN]=Kupfer
GenericName=Application Launcher
GenericName[ca]=Llançador d'aplicació
GenericName[cs]=Spouštěč aplikací
GenericName[da]=Programopstarter
GenericName[de]=Anwendungsstarter
GenericName[el]=Εκκινητής εφαρμογής
GenericName[es]=Lanzador de aplicaciones
GenericName[eu]=Aplikazioen abiarazlea
GenericName[fr]=Lanceur d'applications
GenericName[gl]=Iniciador de aplicativos
GenericName[hu]=Alkalmazásindító
GenericName[it]=Lanciatore di applicazioni
GenericName[ko]=응용 프로그램 실행 아이콘
GenericName[nb]=Programstarter
GenericName[nl]=Programmastarter
GenericName[pl]=Aktywator programów
GenericName[pt]=Lançador de Aplicações
GenericName[pt_BR]=Lançador de aplicativos
GenericName[ru]=Средство запуска приложений
GenericName[sl]=Zaganjalnik programov
GenericName[sv]=Programstartare
GenericName[tr]=Uygulama Çalıştırıcı
GenericName[zh_CN]=程序启动器
Comment=Convenient command and access tool for applications and documents
Comment[cs]=Nástroj pro pohodlné provádění příkazů a přístup k aplikacím a dokumentům
Comment[da]=Nemt kommando- og adgangsværktøj til programmer og dokumenter
Comment[de]=Praktisches Befehls- und Zugriffswerkzeug für Anwendungen und Dokumente
Comment[el]=Βολικό εργαλείο εντολών και πρόσβασης για εφαρμογές και έγγραφα
Comment[es]=Herramienta para acceso y manejo de aplicaciones y documentos
Comment[eu]=Komando eta atzipen tresna egokia aplikazio eta dokumentuentzat
Comment[fr]=Outil pratique pour accéder à des documents et lancer des applications
Comment[gl]=Ferramenta cómoda para controlar e acceder a aplicativos e documentos
Comment[hu]=Kényelmes parancs és hozzáférési eszköz az alkalmazásokhoz és dokumentumokhoz
Comment[it]=Comodo comando e strumento di accesso per applicazioni e documenti
Comment[ko]=편리하게 응용프로그램이나 문서에 접근하고 명령을 내릴 수 있는 도구
Comment[nb]=Praktiskt kommandoverktøy for programmer og dokumenter 
Comment[nl]=Handige opdracht- en toegangshulp voor programma's en documenten
Comment[pl]=Wygodne narzędzie do uruchamiania programów i otwierania dokumentów
Comment[pt]=Ferramenta conveniente para acesso e gestão de aplicações e documentos
Comment[pt_BR]=Uma conveniente ferramenta de comando e acesso para aplicativos e documentos
Comment[ru]=Удобный инструмент для быстрого доступа к программам и документам
Comment[sl]=Prikladno orodje za izvajanje ukazov in dostopa do programov in dokumentov
Comment[sv]=Praktiskt kommandoprogram för åtkomst av program och dokument
Comment[zh_CN]=方便的命令和操作程序或文档的工具
Icon=kupfer
Exec=python /home/user/.local/share/kupfer/kupfer.py %F
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;
StartupNotify=true
X-UserData=$CONFIG/kupfer;$DATA/kupfer;$CACHE/kupfer
Terminal=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for "Startup Applications" in the dash and click on that program. Then click add and in the command section put `python /home/user/.local/share/kupfer/kupfer.py`, which according to the desktop file is the command to start Kupfer.

See also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-every-time-i-log-in) for more information.

Comment: Sounds good. The splash screen shows up and `kupfer.py` is listed in the list of processes. However it does not react to the assign keyboard shortcut. When I start the program manually it does also not show up by keyboard shortcut. - Worth mentioning: The correct executable might be `~./local/bin/kupfer` which I found now. No difference though with the behavior.

Comment: Is python-keybinder installed? run `sudo apt-get install python-keybinder`.

Comment: @JJD could you tell me if that worked.

Comment: Thank you - but I cannot test it until Monday. I will keep you informed.

Comment: I installed `python-keybinder` now. When I start Ubuntu the `kupfer.py` process is running. The keyboard shortcut does not reveal the application though.

Comment: It might be because of a [keyboard shortcut bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322)

Comment: @JJD Have you tried installing Kupfer from apt-get? I just did it on my computer and the keyboard shortcut worked.

Comment: I have been running the release version for a long time. The problem is that it crashes very often. That is why I want to try if the latest version is more stable.

Comment: @JJD I installed the source version over the original by running `./waf configure --prefix=/usr` instead of `./waf configure`. This causes the new version to have the configuration of the old. I would remove the new one completely and the startup applications entry. Then extract the new version from the archive (don't use the last one), then you shouldn't have problems. If it doesn't startup automatically add `python /usr/share/kupfer/kupfer` to the menu.

Comment: Meanwhile, I believe it is a general **keyboard shortcut bug** since I also cannot switch the input language with a shortcut.

Comment: @JJD OK, I saw that above, but you didn't mention that it affected anything except Kupfer. Though when I installed Kupfer the first thing that I noticed is that the default key combination was the same as the one to start IBUS. Which is Ubuntu's default input language switcher. If Kupfer is running right you could click on it's icon in the top bar and under settings should be an option to change the key combination, since mabey they are conflicting.

Comment: @JJD That link you provided gave a list of software to install that should solve that bug. There are PPAs that you would need to add, but they provide instructions on how to do that. Also you should as "How to get keyboard shortcuts to work in Kupfer" as another question, that way it will get more attention, and you will get more answers.

Comment: I found a [similar question complaining about not-working keystrokes](http://askubuntu.com/questions/71990/how-can-i-get-kupfer-to-respond-to-keystrokes).

Comment: @JJD One of the responses to that question mentioned a debug mode could you try that and post anything significant that Kupfer outputs.

Comment: I posted the output [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/71990/how-can-i-get-kupfer-to-respond-to-keystrokes#comment656892_212178).

Comment: @JJD This line makes me think that the problem is not with the key combinations. `[kupfer.ui.browser]WindowController: Trying to register <Ctrl>space to spawn kupfer.. success`. I also noticed that the wnck module is not loading. That is related to libwnck, which is used for creating application switchers and similar utilities. It's possible that this is what is causing the problem. `apt-get install python-wnck` might help.

Comment: Success! After [disabling most of the plugins (incl. Firefox)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/71990/how-can-i-get-kupfer-to-respond-to-keystrokes/212178?noredirect=1#comment657360_212178), quit, restart - Kupfer works. However, it was not Firefox or `python-wnck` since it works with and without both. Thanks anyways!!

Comment: @JJD that's good. At this point i would be activating plugins, try five at a time, and restarting Kupfer to find out which are causing the problem, that way you can still get the benefits of the plugins. Although if you don't need them it might be better for performance if you leave them off anyway.